# Changing or defining default height and width of self hosted wordpress videos

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html5-video

I am manually uploading videos to my Wordpress site, I upload them and use the video blocks function on the post page to embed them in the posts. After I open the post the videos are not in the container. The width x height is 1900x800px, its running from left to right covering the whole sidebar and at the bottom covering the related posts area.

I want the videos to have a default height (for all videos). When I inspect element to check for the elements so I can use custom css to fix it, it shows the following

```
<video controls="" src="https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/videoname.mp4"></video>
```

I tried using the following custom css (one by one)

```
.video {
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
}

.video src {
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
}

.video control src {
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
 }
```

but none of these change anything and the video player still is the same.

There are no css classes, the wordpress posts page html shows this

```
<figure class="wp-block-video"><video controls src="https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/videoname.mp4"></video></figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using CSS selectors correctly. You are using `.video` to try to select the `<video>` element.

- To select an *element*, use just the element tag name, e.g. `video`, `div`, `p` etc
- To select a *class*, precede the class name with a `.` e.g. `.myvideoclass`
- To select an element that has a specific class, use both the element tag name and class (without as space between them) e.g. `video.myvideoclass`

So in your case, you would use:

```
video {
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

If you wanted to use a class, you can add a class to the video element in the html (without the `.`) and then select the class in the CSS with the `.` e.g.

```
<video class="myvideoclass" controls="" src="https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/videoname.mp4"></video>

/* select any element with the class "myvideo" */
.myvideoclass{
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
}

/* Or to select ONLY video elements with the class "myvideo" */
video.myvideoclass{
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

I suggest you do some online tutorials about CSS it understand how yo use it, this one is a good starting point: [**Mozilla Developer CSS tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_is_structured)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I understand that and I edited the question to add more details, there are no css classes defined. Here is what the embed code from the default video block looks like in html

<figure class="wp-block-video"><video controls src="https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/videoname.mp4"></video></figure>

Comment: Yes, I can see there are no classes defined, but your CSS is trying to use classes! My first example shows you how to write CSS that uses the selectors for the `video` *element* without classes (note that it *doesn't* have the `.`). Did you try that?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried but it didnt do anything as well. I am going to make a new css class for it and then use that class. But I don't know how to replace all the 300 videos except manually changing each one

Comment: Its possible you have a CSS rule that's taking precedence over your `video` rule. In the inspector, what CSS rules are being applied to the video element? Your css needs to override whatever it is setting, so for example, if the video already has a `min-width` set, then this could be applied instead. Let us know what CSS is showing in the inspector and we can help with how to override that.

Comment: Element style is not showing anything and the custom code I used 

video {
    width: 980px;
    height: 560px;
}

Its shown as crossed out - I added a new css class and then modified the above code and it worked

Comment: Glad its working! If your rule is showing crossed out, then this means that the CSS is correct but that some other rule is overriding it. Using a class makes your rule more specific and this can then override the overriding rule (depending on how specific it is). The link I included has a section on specificity which might come in handy, because it can get very complex as more rules get added by plugins, themes etc :)